# Substring a char c++

Tags: c++, string, char, substring

> Untitled1.cpp request for member 'substr' in 'ReceiveBuf', which is of non-class type 'char[1024]'

I want to remove everything after space but I have no idea how to do it with char, I only know how to do it with a string.

Comment: Replace the space with a zero-value character.

Comment: May we see the code that produces this error?

Comment: size_t pos = ReceiveBuf.find(" ");
ReceiveBuf.substr(0,pos);

Comment: Add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array contains a string or you are sure that there is space character in the array then you can write

```
if ( char *p = strchr( ReceiveBuf, ' ' ) ) *p = '\0';
```

or

```
ReceiveBuf[ strcspn( ReceiveBuf, " \t" ) ] = '\0';
```

Or you can create a new object of the type std::string the following way

```
std::string s( ReceiveBuf, strcspn( ReceiveBuf, " \t" ) );
```

Comment: thanks man, what if I want to remove everything BEFORE the space and not after? how do I alter it?

Comment: @user7157477 You should use standard C function memmove or create an object of type std::string starting from the space.

Comment: this is fully solved, thank you all for the help. This made my day :)